# Does QPython2 supports Selenium?

Tags: selenium, qpython

I did install selenium on my qpython2 by using:

```
pip install selenium
```

And it downloaded selenium

I had a Firefox browser on my android phone so I tested if it will work like it did on my pc:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.somewebsite.com/)

print 'done'
```

But it gives me an error like this:

ipts/.last_tmp.py" && exit        <
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/sdcard0/qpython/scripts/.last_tmp.py", line 3, in 
    browser=webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.3.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in **init**
    self.service = Service(executable_path, log_path=log_path)
  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.3.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/service.py", line 44, in **init**
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'geckodriver.log'
1|u0_a125@A536:/ $

[UPD]: I was wondering if my mistake was not installing 'geckodriver' on android? But I cannot find geckodriver for android.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you solve it? I also need to do this :(